# Toggle menu not showing up - Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I not sure about what my Toggle menu is not displaying in Tablet and Mobile.

I checked it 5 times but I just can´t find the error.

I please check my codeply  http://www.codeply.com/go/rKSNVkLFaY

Any idea?

Thanks :-)

Comment: There does not appear to be any element with the ID of `navbar-ex1-collapse`.  The nav toggle isn't targeting anything.  Looks like you might have changed `navbar-ex1-collapse` to a `class` rather than an `id` attribute on `#navbar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the classes `collapse` and `navbar-collapse` from the `#test` ul => `<ul id="test" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">`.

Change `data-target` => `data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"`, you need to add the dot for 'class'.

Here's a working example: http://jsbin.com/dipefamiya/3/

**UPDATE**

You are also setting a `height` property on `#NavGerster` that conflicts with the menu. Maybe you can find another way to achieve the same thing? If you comment it out it will work.

`#NavGerster{
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    background-color: #8a7d78;
    /*height: 74px;*/
}`

Comment: I tried your Code in my server and Codeply (codeply.com/go/rKSNVkLFaY) but is still not working. I´dont know what can be the reason. It seems that something is moving (just the borders are kind of shown) Could I be a CSS Issue? Do you have any idea?

Comment: The `height` property on `#NavGerster` seems to prevent it from expanding.